# In ReactJs, how can I get the score of my trivia game to be posted through REST API?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm making a trivia game where the data is on MYSQL. My code for calculating the score is functioning properly. However, how do I get this score to be posted through REST API? I have this as my handleScore for when the user submits the game to calculate their score.

```
    const handleScore = () => {
      let s = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        if(questions[i].answer == myAnswers[i]){
         s++
        }
      }

      setScore(((s*10)/questions.length)*10)
    }
```

I have this to fetch and POST:

```
    const addScore = () => {
      const init = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(score)
      };
  
      fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/score/${scoreId}`, init)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 201 || response.status === 400) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            return Promise.reject(`Unexpected status code: ${response.status}`);
          }
        })
        .then(data => {
          if (data.scoreId) {
            history.push({pathname: `/score/${scoreId}`, state: { scoreId: scoreId }}); 
          } else {
  
            setErrors(data);
          }
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    };
```

Would I need to combine these two in order to save the score? Right now, there is a button for finishing the game and it only has "handleScore" as the onClick.

Submit button:

```
<button onClick= {handleScore}>Submit</button>
```

My question is, would I need to combine the following code I wrote above? Or, would I need to have my onClick to have 2 functions with 1 function to save the score to MYSQL and the other function to calculate for the user to view the score?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Are you asking how you should be initiating the fetch()? You can just wrap it in a function and call the function. It doesn't matter if you choose to combine the code to do both, or call them from two separate functions. That comes down to preference and how versatile you would like your function that contains fetch() to be.

Comment: My question is, how do I get my newly calculated score and have it POST in Rest API? I have them as separate functions right now. My newly calculated score is indicated as "s." How do I get that into addScore so that it can be put into MYSQL through Rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ideally each function should have own responsibility, in my opinion the best variant here is to use this 2 functions in such way:

```
const handleScore = () => {
      let s = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        if(questions[i].answer == myAnswers[i]){
         s++
        }
      }
      return ((s*10)/questions.length)*10
    }

const addScore = (score) => {
      const init = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(score)
      };
  
      fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/score/${scoreId}`, init)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 201 || response.status === 400) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
            return Promise.reject(`Unexpected status code: ${response.status}`);
          }
        })
        .then(data => {
          if (data.scoreId) {
            history.push({pathname: `/score/${scoreId}`, state: { scoreId: scoreId }}); 
          } else {
  
            setErrors(data);
          }
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    };

const handleSubmit = () => {
  const scoreResult = handleScore(); // responsoble only for calculating score
  setScore(scoreResult) // not required, but you can write, if you need latest score somewhere else to use
  addScore(scoreResult) // responsoble backend and pushing to next route
}

<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
```